# incomplete migrations- stuck in generating new migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I am having a very bad situation here, working on a `Laravel 5` project. previously developed by another developer. That developer at start created couple of tables using `migration generators` and added some `columns` using migrations. After that, he added table `columns` straight away using some sql `GUI`. I was given the `sql dump` which i imported and set it up on my local machine, now when i created a `table` using `php artisan make:migration create_myTableName_table --create="myTableName"` the table migration is created successfully, but, when i did `php artisan migrate` it's giving me `SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'someTable' already exists` I checked migrations folder and matched it with current version of `someTable` and i can see the columns are different, same with other tables aswell.

What should be the best case to handle this in this situation, i want to keep up with `Laravel migrations generator` so that in future if any other developer want to work on this project he just has to run migration command to migrate database or to create tables or create columns... Should i re-write all migrations ? pleas help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and dirty?**

Delete current migration files. Clear your `migrations` table and export the whole DB. Put the SQL dump in the repo and instruct other devs to import it before they run `php artisan migrate`. With the dump imported and `migrations` table truncated, you can create new migrations with no further collisions with the legacy migrations.

**Feeling ambitious?**

Use a package like **[migrations-generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)** to generate migrations based on your current DB structure. Then, migrate away.

Comment: If you delete current migrations and truncate migrations table, the Ambitious way may be just as fast as the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 1):

Given your situation, I’d put the **.sql** export in your repository, clear out the old, broken migrations, and create a new one that initially imports the database dump. Then just create migrations as normal going forward.